# Get a queryset from another queryset via OneToOne relation

Tags: python, django

I have two models as

```
class modelA(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and

```
class modelB(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     age = models.IntegerField()
```

I have created a query as:

```
query_set = modelB.objects.filter(age__gte=20)
```

Now how can I get a queryset of modelA from query_set

Comment: Whad do you mean by "get a qs of modelA from qs"? You need only `modelA` fields in result or you want to filter by `modelA` fields in your queryset?

Comment: I need the queryset of `modelA` after the above filtering and then apply filters in it.  One thing will be sure that  users having `modelB` will always have `modelA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
list_comprehension
user_ids = [item.user.pk for item in query_set]
```

use the user_ids to filter in the modelA

```
modelA.objects.filter(user__id__in=user_ids)

this will give you all modelA objects that share the same user with modelB
```

Something even better would be to just query from the **User** model.

```
users = User.objects.filter(modelb__age__gte=20)
```

if you want to check that the modelb or modela relation is not empty add the following filters to it:

```
users = User.objects.filter(modelb__isnull=False, modela__isnull=False, modelb__age__gte=20)
```

from the user you can do like

```
for user in users:
    user.modela
    user.modelb
```

Comment: Can `users = User.objects.filter(modelb__age__gte=20)`  be applied even if all User model don't have `modelB`

Comment: Good question, the best thing would be to try it out. I think it will only pick up the users where modelb exists. But this is a guess.

Comment: I tried it and it returns the users whose `modelB` exists

Comment: if you want to check if it is not none you can add that to the filter. so it becomes like: User.objects.filter(modelb__isnul=False, modela__isnull=False, modelb__age__gte=20)